# How do I extract short digit sequences from two different integers and compare them?

Tags: python, integer, compare, python-3.3, digits

I'm new to Python and I'm having trouble with one of my assignment.

So the question is: 
I have to obtain two positive integers from the user (one longer and one shorter). Then I have to loop through the longer integer (from left to right) and to check to see if the shorter integer appears inside the longer integer. And I have to report the position of the matches and the number of matches. 
***I am not allowed to use strings and list to do this assignment ):**

Examples of the result is supposed to be like this:

Eg 1. 
Input a positive longer integer: 123456789 
Input a positive shorter integer: 123
Found a match at position 0
End: found 1 matches

Eg 2.
Input a positive longer integer: 123456789 
Input a positive shorter integer: 789
Found a match at position 6
End: found 1 matches

Eg 3.
Input a positive longer integer: 12312312312231222 
Input a positive shorter integer: 22
Found a match at position 10
Found a match at position 14
Found a match at position 15
End: found 3 matches

Eg 4.
Input a positive longer integer: 12312312312231222 
Input a positive shorter integer: 55
End: cannot find any match

So what I did so far:

```
# Ask user for positve longer integer number
longInt = int(input("Input a positive longer integer: "))

# Ask user for positive shorter integer number 
shortInt = int(input("Input a positive shorter integer: "))

# Count number of digits in both longer and shorter integer numbers
import math
longLength = int(math.log10(longInt))+1
shortLength = int (math.log10(shortInt))+1

for i in range(0,longLength):
    for x in range(0,shortLength):
        while (longLength > 0):
            longDigit = longInt % 10 **(longLength) // 10**(longLength-1)
            longLength-=1
            print (longDigit)
        while (shortLength > 0):
            shortDigit = shortInt % 10**(shortLength) // 10**(shortLength-1)
            shortLength-=1
            print (shortDigit)
```

Please do help! Thanks! (:

Comment: Thanks for saying that's an assignment (lots of people does not have the integrity to do so) and posting every information available. I'm not sure comparing every digit is the most efficient solution : it would be preferable to extract sub-integer from longInt and compare it to shortInt.

Comment: So I can't use a while loop to loop through longInt? Cause I'm kinda stuck at where I have to put in the comparison part for the two integers if I use a while loop, but if I don't use the while loop, I'm not sure how to loop through the integer to extract the digits.

Comment: Do you know arithmetic shifting : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift ? That's the same method , but with power of tens'.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to offset your longInt several times to extract all the shortInt-length integers ( like bit-shifting, but with power of tens' instead of twos').

```
import math

# Ask user for positve longer integer number
longInt = 123456789 

# Ask user for positive shorter integer number 
shortInt = 1234

# Count number of digits in both longer and shorter integer numbers

longLength  = int( math.log10(longInt) )+1
shortLength = int( math.log10(shortInt))+1

for offset in range(0, longLength):
  subInt = (longInt// 10**(offset)) % 10 **(shortLength) 
  print(subInt)
```

Result :

> > 6789
> >         5678
> >         4567
> >         3456
> >         2345
> >         1234
> >         123
> >         12
> >         1

Comment: I did it accordingly as you suggested, but it goes through the integer from right to left, so the position is reversed. May I know if there's a way to do it from left to right? 

for offset in range(0,longLength):
    subInt = longInt // 10**(offset) % 10**(shortLength)
    if (subInt == shortInt):
        print ("Found a match at position ",offset)

Comment: I've tried changing it to for offset in range (longLength,0,-1) but it doesn't really work. How do I get it to go through the longInt from left to right, instead of righ to left?

Comment: range(longLength,0,-1) will enumerate integer from longLength to zero in reverse order : in other words, from 0 to longLength ! (you've made a double flip which nullify itself). Just use range(0,longLength,-1) or range(longLength, 0)

Comment: I've tried range(0,longLength,-1) and range(longLength,0) before too, they don't work too. It is because I have to change the computation for subInt?

Comment: Is there any other way to reverse subInt? (Such that it loops through longInt from left to right instead of right to left?)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along these lines:

```
def i2l(i):
    rtr=[]
    while i:
        rtr.insert(0, i%10)
        i//=10
    return rtr

longer=int(input("Input a positive longer integer: "))    
shorter=int(input("Input a positive shorter integer: "))

ll=i2l(longer)   
ls=i2l(shorter)

answer=[]
for idx in [i for i,e in enumerate(ll) if e==ls[0]]:    
    try:
        all_good=all(ll[i+idx]==e for i,e in enumerate(ls))    
    except IndexError:
        all_good=False 
    if all_good:
        answer.append(idx)

if answer:
    s='index' if len(answer)==1 else 'indices'
    print '{} found in {} at {} {}'.format(shorter,longer,s,answer)
else:
    print '{} not found in {}'.format(shorter,longer)
```

Now run it:

```
Input a positive longer integer: 12312312312231222
Input a positive shorter integer: 22
22 found in 12312312312231222 at indices [10, 14, 15]

Input a positive longer integer: 12312312312231222
Input a positive shorter integer: 4
4 not found in 12312312312231222
```